# three.js : Issue on multiple material for extrude geometry

Tags: three.js

I am using three.js extrude funtion to draw a geometry and I would like to add to it 2 textures, One for Top and Bottom, and one for the other sides.

According to [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074877/three-js-apply-different-material-to-extruded-shape) it seems to be possible. But I do not manage to make it works.

Here is my code :

```
    //Create BaseForm (Bottom)
    var shape = new THREE.Shape();
    shape.moveTo(0,0);
    shape.lineTo(0,2);
    shape.lineTo(0.5,1.5);
    shape.lineTo(1,2);
    shape.lineTo(1,0);
    shape.lineTo(0.5,0.5);
    shape.lineTo(0,0);
    //Extrude XScores
    var extrudeSettings={amount: 50, bevelEnabled: false, material: 0, extrudeMaterial: 1, steps: 10};
    var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );

    var material1 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0x111111, roughness: 0.1, metalness: 0.4, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0x8dbe8d, roughness: 0.7, metalness: 0, side: THREE.DoubleSide});

    var materials = [
        material1,
        material2];

    var localmesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry,materials);     
    return localmesh;
```

But only One texture is applied for all the faces (material2).

NB: As I was having Issues on extruding on small objects, I use earcut.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Try `var localmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);`

Comment: It works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this:

```
var localmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
```

`THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterial()` is intended for another purpose. It just creates two objects of the same geometry, but with different materials in the same place.